# SQL Error on Order by and group by

Tags: sql-server

This SQL works in mysql but I can't do this in SQL Server.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(postnID) AS Total, 
        postnID, 
        Unit_DBM, 
        job_type, 
        level, 
        internal_plantilla, 
        INCID, 
        ITEM_NO_2005, 
        position_type, 
        position_status 
    FROM paf_plantilla 
    GROUP BY 
        internal_plantilla, 
        level, 
        INCID, 
        postnID, 
        position_status 
    ORDER BY 
        internal_plantilla, 
        postnID
) AS num
```

Error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Do you encounter any error? If so, please post the said error.

Comment: Your query could be simplified to: `SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM paf_plantilla
GROUP BY 
 postnID, 
 Unit_DBM, 
 job_type, 
 level, 
 internal_plantilla, 
 INCID, 
 ITEM_NO_2005, 
 position_type, 
 position_status `

Comment: So did you consider removing the order by clause before posting here?  A  lot less key stokes.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work in any non MySQL implementation of SQL.

- Non aggregates in aggregate queries must be `grouped by`
- `ORDER BY` without `TOP` in a subquery is most likely not going to do what you think  it will (may not give an error but it's not right either)

Because of the first point it's very hard to work out what the correct query - some kind of count of combinations of other things.  If you explain what I might be able to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select columns which are not in the `group by` clause. Since you are doing a `count`, you really don't need the `order by` clause. Try the below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(postnID) AS Total, 
        postnID, 
        Unit_DBM, 
        job_type, 
        level, 
        internal_plantilla, 
        INCID, 
        ITEM_NO_2005, 
        position_type, 
        position_status 
    FROM paf_plantilla 
    GROUP BY 
        postnID, 
        Unit_DBM, 
        job_type, 
        level, 
        internal_plantilla, 
        INCID, 
        ITEM_NO_2005, 
        position_type, 
        position_status 
) AS num
```

Comment: But  I am grouping it only on internal_plantilla, level, INCID, postnID, position_status. This SQL shows all the records in the table.

Comment: Then you need to remove redundant columns from your `select` list.